# How is Discussion post "Popularity" calculated

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, community

Does anybody know how the "Popularity" column value is calculated for a Community discussion post?

I found [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/bedece85-2cdb-4a70-b110-e798080a9d74/sp2013-discussion-board-popularity-values?forum=sharepointgeneral), but the "answers" all point to how to access or something else about **popularity trends** which is not the same thing at all!

[This thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/bedece85-2cdb-4a70-b110-e798080a9d74/sp2013-discussion-board-popularity-values?forum=sharepointgeneral) mentions looking in `sp.ui.discussions.js` but I'm not seeing it in there, at least easily.

Does anybody else know how it is calculated?